# Jest test case failing with StyleSheet.create

Tags: react-native, jestjs

I am currently facing an issue where the every pages Stylesheet .create is the cause of the failure and not sure entirely why it is.. but can someone give me an explanation or a solution?

And one more thing, without enzyme (I am using react-native 0.56, I haven't found an enzyme installation file just yet.) can I simulate a press button based on a class such as a homepage with two buttons as a test case with both on Press?

● Test suite failed to run

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

  162 | }
  163 |
> 164 | const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      |                           ^
  165 |     container: {
  166 |         flex: 1,
  167 |         justifyContent: 'center',

  at Object.<anonymous> (components/landingpage.js:164:27)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/landingpage.spec.js:3:1)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to mock it.

```
jest.mock('react-native', () => {
    let items = {};
        StyleSheet: {
            create: () => ({})
        },
    }
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't that changing the whole react native object and disabling the rest of its components? Combining with `jest.requireActual('react-native')` should be the standard way to go.

Answer (score 10):

Correct syntax for Amin's answer:

```
jest.mock('react-native', () => {
  return {
    StyleSheet: {
      create: () => ({}),
    },
  };
});
```